# SQL: Finding where value appears more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find records where "subfield a" appears more than once.

This query works great for finding rows that have any subfield a at all:

```
SELECT Distinct 
    BT.BibliographicRecordID as recordid
FROM 
    BibliographicTags BT with (nolock)
JOIN 
    BibliographicSubfields BS with (nolock) ON BS.BibliographicTagID = BT.BibliographicTagID
WHERE 
    BT.TagNumber = 049
    AND BS.subfield ='a'
```

But I'm trying for something with the effect of:

```
SELECT Distinct 
    BT.BibliographicRecordID as recordid
FROM 
    BibliographicTags BT with (nolock)
JOIN 
    BibliographicSubfields BS with (nolock) ON BS.BibliographicTagID = BT.BibliographicTagID
WHERE 
    BT.TagNumber = 049
    AND BS.subfield = 'a' APPEARS MORE THAN ONCE
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can subfield 'a' appear more than once for the same TagNumber?

Comment: The `with (nolock)` sort of screams SQL Server, so I added the tag.

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simple `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause does the trick?

```
SELECT BT.BibliographicRecordID as recordid
FROM BibliographicTags BT with (nolock)
JOIN BibliographicSubfields BS with (nolock)
ON BS.BibliographicTagID = BT.BibliographicTagID
AND BS.subfield ='a'
WHERE BT.TagNumber = 049
GROUP BY BT.BibliographicRecordID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

BTW, make sure you have a very good reason to use the `with (nolock)` hints.  It's generally not what you want.

Relevant: [SQL Server NOLOCK Hint & other poor ideas.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Actually, without fully understanding your data model, the following query is more likely to give you the data as you expect:

```
SELECT Distinct BT.BibliographicRecordID as recordid
  FROM BibliographicTags BT
 WHERE BT.BibliographicTagID IN (
                SELECT BT.BibliographicTagID
                  FROM BibliographicTags BT
                  JOIN BibliographicSubfields BS
                    ON BS.BibliographicTagID = BT.BibliographicTagID
                   AND BS.subfield = 'a'
                 GROUP BY BT.BibliographicTagID
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is the [SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fe6a/1) to see the query in action.  Hopefully you'll be able to spot what is different about your query?  You are using SQL Server, right?

Comment: When I try this I get a " The COUNT function requires 1 argument(s).. " error. I think it's a sign I'm over my head. Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: Are you able to run the subquery part only?  `SELECT BT.BibliographicTagID ... HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`.  It sounds like you didn't type the `*` in `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Still get the same error when just doing the subquery

Comment: Did you put the `*`?  Because I'll get the same error you did if I just type `COUNT()`.  The error is basically saying that there needs to be something between the parenthesis.

Comment: I did put the * but did notice I got the error with or without it

Comment: Very odd.  Must be some very small detail that is tripping you. Can you please edit your post, and copy-paste the exact query that is not working.  Unless it really is identical to what I posted.

Comment: It really is identical. I copied and pasted it:

Comment: The let me set up a little SQLFiddle, to give you a running example.  Maybe it will help to clear up what is not working.  I'll edit in a few minutes

Comment: I edited my post and added the SQL Fiddle link.  Give it a try.